# WPF - GUI not updating when calling different class? (TCP application)

Tags: c#, wpf, tcp, controls, textblock

I have a fairly weird question? I have seen on web how to pass control from main class to another class, and this is said to work, but it does not? 
What I am trying to do is create a simple asynchronous TCP client-server connection, which would send messsage from client to server. Problem is when I want to update client's textblock, application exits (no error just closes). I only have one main thread so I don't think I need to have an Invoke.

Code from main class:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void connect_ClickEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            _statusPanel.Text += "Sending request to server (IP address: " + _ipTextBox.Text + ", port number: " + _portTextBox.Text + ")\n";
            _statusPanel.Text += "Connecting.....\n";

            AsynchronousClient.setStatusPanel(_statusPanel);
            AsynchronousClient.setPort(Convert.ToInt32(_portTextBox.Text));
            AsynchronousClient.setIpAddress(_ipTextBox.Text);
            AsynchronousClient.StartClient(_message.Text);

            _statusPanel.Text += "... connection established!\n";
            _statusPanel.Text += "Enter the string to be transmitted !\n";
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            _statusPanel.Text += ee.StackTrace + "\n";
        }

    }

}
```

Code from another class:

```
public class AsynchronousClient
{
    // The port number for the remote device.
    private static int port;
    private static IPAddress ipAd;
    public static TextBlock statusPanel;

    public static void setStatusPanel(TextBlock status)
    {
        statusPanel = status; //That's my setter for statusPanel which I want to update
    }          

    public static void StartClient(string message)
    {
        // Connect to a remote device.
        try
        {
            IPAddress ipAddress = ipAd;
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);

            Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            client.BeginConnect(remoteEP,
                new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
            connectDone.WaitOne();

            string sendingMessage = message + "<EOF>";
            Send(client, sendingMessage);
            sendDone.WaitOne();

            Receive(client);
            receiveDone.WaitOne();

            client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            client.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            statusPanel.Text += e.ToString() + "\n";
        }
    }

    private static void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            client.EndConnect(ar);

            //This next line is where my program closes without error
            statusPanel.Text = "Socket connected to " + client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString() + "\n";

            connectDone.Set();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            statusPanel.Text += e.ToString() + "\n";
        }
    }
```

**If I replace "statusPanel.text" with "Console.WriteLine" everything works just fine! Anybody knows what I am doing wrong?  **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***AsyncCallback will be called on separate thread and not on main thread*** so you can't update textBox value from other thread. You can only do that from main UI thread.

So, you have to delegate it on main thread like this:

```
statusPanel.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => 
                     statusPanel.Text = "Socket connected to " + 
                     client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString() + "\n"));
```

Comment: I tried to use statusPanel.Dispatcher (code which you posted) and it didn't work. The UI freezes!

Comment: The problem lies somewhere in your code then. Most likely after your `BeginInvoke` operation where you are waiting on some threads here `sendDone.WaitOne()` and `receiveDone.WaitOne();`. Try comment out these lines(just for testing to identify the problem) and see if problem still persist.

Comment: If I change .Invoke to .BeginInvoke I get error for client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString() (cannot access disposed object). So how can i tell thread to complete updating first and then proceed?

Comment: No I didn't meant to change Invoke to BeginInvoke. It has to be Invoke only. I meant when you call the delegate `client.BeginConnect(remoteEP, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);`. After this line you call multiple methods and wait on them by using `WaitOne` but I don't see you ever set those waitOne's from your code so your UI thread will continue to wait on them till you set them. Try commenting out the code just to see if that's the problem area. The code I posted won't hang UI for sure.

Comment: You had right. It was something with WaitOne() and thread stopped!

Answer (score 0):

You method `ConnectCallback` will not be executed on the WPF User Interface thread, but instead will be invoked by the socket class on a background thread of the thread pool. In this method, you set the Text of the `StatusPanel`.

Use `StatusOanel.Dispatcher.Invoke` to execute your method on the UI Thread. If you want to learn more about it, this article might be a thing: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx